# No Longer Able to Deploy VirtoCommerce from GitHub

Tags: azure, github, virtocommerce

In the past I have successfully deployed VirtoCommerce to Azure from GitHub using the "Deploy to Azure" button.  But today, using my Azure free trial subscription, I am receiving an error message.

Using the "Free" SKU, when I attempt to deploy, it gets to the "Configuring SQL Server Firewall Rules" step and then fails with deployment error, "The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type".

Does this no longer work with a free trial account?  As I said, it worked before, so something must have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Web edition of the Azure SQL Database is now retired.

I have changed the database edition to the Basic (the new minimal edition) in azuredeploy.json, so now everything should work again.